# Unable to translate Unicode character \uD83D at index 716 to specified code page. EPPLUS

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error in ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray() while exporting excel. I have tried everything as UTF-8 encoding etc but nothing works.

Below is my code

```
public void function Export()
{

    ExcelPackage package = ExportUtil.GetMacroEnabledExtract(ds, extractName, "Comments");

    Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + ExportUtil.getFileName(extractName, ".xlsm") + "\"");
    Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();

}
```

export function

```
public static ExcelPackage GetMacroEnabledExtract(DataSet ds, string extractName, string dataSheetName)
    {


string appDataPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data");
    string filePath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "MacroTemplate.xlsm");
    FileInfo templateFile = new FileInfo(filePath);

    ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(templateFile, false);
    string fileName = getFileName(extractName, ".xlsm");

    createDataWorkSheetMacroEnabled(package, ds.Tables[0], dataSheetName, templateFile); //Sheet 1


    return package;
    }

private static void createDataWorkSheetMacroEnabled(ExcelPackage package, DataTable table, string worksheetName, FileInfo file)
    {

    ExcelWorksheet wsData = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    wsData.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);

    ExcelTextFormat format = new ExcelTextFormat();
    format.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    wsData.Cells.LoadFromText(file, format);

    }
```

Comment: D83D is in the UTF-16 high surrogates block, i.e. it's part of a single codepoint split into two parts. I guess EPPlus doesn't know how to assemble these back together so it can then reencode the single code point in UTF-8. You'll either need to enhance EPPlus to process UTF-16 or drop or replace the character.

Comment: I have tried these  
ExcelTextFormat format = new ExcelTextFormat();
        format.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        wsData.Cells.LoadFromText(file, format);

Still giving me errors in 
An exception of type 'System.Text.EncoderFallbackException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to translate Unicode character \uD83D at index 636 to specified code page.

Comment: Hello @Professional, did you managed to solve this?